# Code review has been challenged to a KOTH battle

Tags: discussion

[The corresponding meta post for code review](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8378/a-friendly-challenge), and the [chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63002/programming-puzzles-and-code-golf-vs-code-review).

Currently the plan is to have each side have a team and build resources and a base. Limited resources. The last team standing wins. Currently the two ideas for "winning" is destroy the other sides artifact or have no respawns and last side standing wins.

What are your thoughts?

Comment: I'd love it if there was actually a fully-fledged KoTH challenge before you challenged them.  As it stands, it feels like you are trying to get people to join this competition without knowing what the competition entails.

Comment: If this is seeking ideas on what the contest should be about and whether it's a good idea, that seems perfectly suited to the sandbox.

Comment: @NathanMerrill I gave them the general idea. I have a full sandbox coming out soon

Comment: @trichoplax hyper just said I should warn everyone :P I have the ideas

Comment: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/13492#13492 sandbox

Comment: So, I frequent both sites. Am I going to have to pick a side? (Am I going to get exiled for heresy?)

Comment: @CAD97 Probably not, if you write two bots. (Yes.)

Comment: @CAD97 (Heretic.)

Comment: What will the level of coding knowledge be to be able to participate?

Comment: @mich well not high. It is more about problem solving. Most of the code will be simple

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Challenge Declined

Please read my answer on [Code Review Meta](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8387/31562)

In addition, some of 200_success' original fears seem to have come true:

> @EBrown You're either with us, or you are the enemy! – ncalmbeblpaicr0011 Aug 1 at 15:37
>
> -1 PPCG always wins. On PPCG, a PPCG user always wins every challenge. – NoOneIsHere 21 hours ago

We're really not interested in that kind of talk for something that was supposed to be a friendly fight. But even without that kind of talk, we feel that battling sites against each other is not a good idea.

Comment: I don't think you're not parsing banter correctly. if there is no play in this, then why would it be fun in the first place? Competition strives for progress. Nobody said in this site's beta that pitting users against each other is a bad Idea. Because we're not doing that. at all. Why do you think this would be different?

Comment: @tuskiomi The fun should be in writing the code, not in talking crap about others. It's not the intention behind the bantering that matters, it is how it is understood.

Answer (score 27):

## Please remember to be respectful!

I certainly hope I don't have to say this as any more than just a quick friendly reminder, but please remember that even with all of our jokes about Code Review folks being crazy about readability and about them beating us to graduation and getting a design (*ahem*), they are all either human beings with feelings or bots that Jon Skeet made when he was bored, and we don't want to offend either.

Joking and playful "insults" is acceptable, but I think I can speak for the community when I say that we don't want this to be any more than a friendly competition. Even if we wish we graduated sooner despite having a better lifetime in beta or that we actually get a design, we're still friends with them after all.

I look forward to this competition. I think it will be a great idea and lots of fun, and we might even be able to get to know them better!

## Treat them like you would treat our own community

We are two separate communities on two separate sites, but we're all a part of StackExchange. Just like you (hopefully) wouldn't break the rules or mess with other bots on our own intrasite KoTHs, "fight" cleanly and respectfully. We don't want another [StackEggs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252393/when-something-that-was-supposed-to-be-fun-became-not-fun) incident, which also happened between the very same two sites.

Comment: `they are all either human beings with feelings or bots that Jon Skeet made when he was bored` - Jon Skeet's bots probably have feelings too.

Comment: It's better to joke and use playful 'insults' one time too little than one time too much.

Comment: @SimonForsberg Certainly, I agree.

Comment: @LordFarquaad I don't think Jon Skeet's bots care too much - it's *him* we should be worried about.